# La pregunta está escrita en inglés. ¿Pero y si está en otro idioma?

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, motivos-de-cierre, idiomas

Cuando se realizan preguntas en inglés, para cerrarla está bien que se reporte como:

> La pregunta está escrita en inglés. El idioma oficial de este sitio es español.

Pero si hubiera una pregunta en francés u otro idioma, debería elegir el mismo motivo. Y esto es algo incoherente: debería ser el reporte algo parecido a lo siguiente:

> La pregunta está escrita en un idioma diferente al idioma oficial de
>   este sitio el cual es español.

Lo que no comprendo es por qué existe directamente "La pregunta está escrita en inglés. El idioma oficial de este sitio es español". ¿Por qué para inglés tiene un mensaje predeterminado? ¿Y los demás lenguajes qué? Ahora me dirán que es el 90% los errores para inglés, ¿pero no podría ser genérico y listo?

¿Por qué todo se trata directamente con el idioma inglés?

Por ejemplo, hay temas acá en Meta que se refieren directamente con el idioma inglés. Pero, ¿qué pasa con los demás idiomas? ¿Los dejamos de lado?

---

### IMPORTANTE

Ayer estaba con Nicolas (nuestro nuevo CM), y justo a la mañana habia salido este tema a la luz.. voy a poner otra respuesta en esta pregunta, para ver si estamos todos de acuerdo con el cambio, de vuelta (aunque ya votamos, fue hace mucho, y prefiero que quede claro que estamos todos de acuerdo).

Comment: Aunque como has contestado mas abajo, has visto casos en otros idiomas, creo que mas del 90% son casos en ingles. De todas formas, si pulsas cerrar, en la opción de no relacionado, está la opción de otros, que puedes poner tu motivo personalizado. Aunque estaría bien, que se colocase una genercia

Comment: Tal vez lo más fácil sería cambiar el mensaje a ___La pregunta no está escrita en español, que es el idioma de este sitio.___

Comment: @fedorqui eso mismo digo, y no mencionar que esta en ingles, seria menos lioso

Comment: On SOru we have the following close reason (in Russian of course). "The question is closed, because on Stack Overflow in Russian it is acceptable to ask only in Russian. Please translate your question into Russian or use Stack Overflow in English."  It is not hard to add the close reason or edit it in the future.

Answer (score 7):

Mismo sentido que la respuesta de Miguel, pero hagámoslo de la siguiente forma:

**A favor: cambiar el texto** a:

> La pregunta está escrita en un idioma diferente al idioma oficial de este sitio, que es el español.

**En contra: dejar el texto que está**:

> La pregunta está escrita en inglés. El idioma oficial de este sitio es
>   español.

Comment: De acuerdo. No entiendo de todos modos por qué hay que implicar al CM en esto, pues es algo que los moderadores pueden hacer.

Comment: No. Al parecer no. El texto no esta al alcance de un moderador.

Comment: Me extraña mucho, pues en toda la red [se] los moderadores tienen la opción y el propio Shog9 lo explica en [How do moderators make changes to the site-specific closed question reasons?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185097/209901)

Comment: @gbianchi ¿cuál es tu fuente?

Comment: Nicolas (el CM) dijo que lo haria el.. Tal vez fue para desligar a los moderadores de esto?? mas alla, si lo puede hacer un mod genial.

Comment: @Rubén Que tampoco es una batalla campal con que lo haga alguien alcanza!

Comment: @gbianchi ¡Oh! que pena :P  Pues ocho votos a favor y ninguno en contra sería suficiente para proceder ¿no?

Comment: @Rubén me pa que estariamos de acuerdo.. jajajaja

Comment: Pues si sí o si no ya lo he "Reportado" para que un moderador tome cartas en el asunto antes de que esto se vuelva una batalla campal :D

Comment: ¡Buen trabajo! 8 votos positivos suena como a consenso absoluto :)

Comment: OK. Si está bien, voy a esperar a que pasen 24 horas desde la publicación de este respuesta (más o menos dentro de 3 horas) por si alguien quiere proporcionar su opinión, y si sigue siendo bien recibida esta opción, procederé con el cambio.

Comment: Ya fue realizado el cambio por el equipo de moderación (previa aprobación) del texto que sugiere Gonzalo, "La pregunta está escrita en un idioma diferente al idioma oficial de este sitio, que es el español". @gbianchi

Answer (score -10):

Hasta ahora esto no ha pasado (creo) y en cualquier caso (y es lo que hacíamos antes de tener este motivo específico) se pueden cerrar por un motivo personalizado.

Yo creo que está bien tenerlo específico por que es la forma de cubrir la gran mayoría de los casos de manera específica. Ser específico en el 99% de los casos es mejor que ser genérico en el 100% ya que el usuario al que se le cierra le queda aún más claro y eso es esencial.

Creo que no queda muy claro a lo que me refiero. Actualmente tenemos la posibilidad de cerrar una pregunta por el motivo en ingles específicamente, pero si hay *otro* idioma se puede cerrar simplemente escribiendo uno mismo el texto que se quiere en "otro motivo". Como explica muy bien [Mariano](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1324/la-pregunta-est%C3%A1-escrita-en-ingl%C3%A9s-pero-si-esta-en-otro-idioma/1325?noredirect=1#comment3487_1325):

Cerrar -> no relacionado porque... -> Otro -> "`Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque está en XXXXXXXX, y debería ser traducida **por el autor** para poder aceptarla en [es.so]. En caso de querer migrarla a un sitio en otro idioma, favor de *reportar* para que un moderador migre la pregunta.`"

Aun así; que decida la comunidad :P:

- +1 (voto a favor) si se quiere **mantener el texto actual.**
- -1 (voto en contra) si se quiere **modificar el texto actual al propuesto.**

**Contabilizan solo los votos en esta respuesta. NO en la pregunta.**

En unos días evaluamos :)

Estado actual:

- 4 votos a favor de mantener (4 votos positivos)
- 5 votos a favor de cambiar el texto actual (5 votos negativos)

No computo mi voto ya que aunque tengo mi opinion prefiero que la comunidad decida. Si llegamos a una diferencia clara (como mínimo de 2 votos) decidimos!

Comment: @MiquelColl creo que se olvidaron de este tema

Comment: @x-rw parece que hay que cambiar el texto del voto de cierre... :D

Comment: Chicos, yo no se que tan valida sea esta consulta en el estado actual de las cosas.. y si reiniciamos la votacion en otra respuesta?

Comment: @gbianchi La pregunta tienen hoy la misma validez que cuando se redactó. Y lo mismo se puede decir de la respuesta. Lo correcto sería implementar lo que aquí se ha decidido. ¿Lo que se escribe y decide en meta tiene algún valor?